# Unknown value in req.param in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters

I'm am learning `node.js` and therefore try to build a simple web app that shows the current news. The `API` that I am using offers several categories for the news.

So I create a route that takes the category as a param. My `routes/index.js`:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const renderHome = require('../controllers/newsController');
const quotesCookie = require('./../middleware/quotesCookie');

router.get('/', quotesCookie, renderHome);
router.get('/:category', quotesCookie, renderHome);


module.exports = router;
```

My `controllers/newsController.js` looks like this:

```
const newsService = require('./../services/newsService');

const renderHome = async ( req, res ) => {
  const category = req.params.category;
  console.log(req.params);

  const quote = res.quoteOfTheDay;

  const { status, msg } = await newsService.topHeadlines(category);

  res.render('home', {
    title: 'News2Go',
    author: quote.author,
    quote: quote.quote,
    articles: msg.articles
  });
};


module.exports = renderHome;
```

When I for instance call `http://localhost:3000/entertainment` the `console.log` in the controller prints this to the console:

```
{ category: 'entertainment' }
{ category: 'sw.js' }
```

I have absolute no clue where the `sw.js` comes from... It appears a few milliseconds after the real category and ensures that `topHeadlines` is called twice.

Did someone know what this is? Did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe you have a service worker (sw.js) register for the 3000 port. Please check in the Devtools of Chrone, in the Tab Application / Service Worker.

Comment: Your right, thanks @Gillespie59.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your web page has a script in it named `sw.js`.  Because of that, the browser will request that with the URL `http://localhost:3000/sw.js` and your `:category` route will handle that request and log a category of `sw.js`.

Remember, ALL resources used on your site will be requested by the browser and will be seen by your Express server as incoming requests.  Not just the top level page, but all scripts, images, fonts, CSS files, etc... used by your pages.

It's generally not a good idea to define a wide-open top level route handler like this:

```
router.get('/:category', ...)
```

Because that will grab ALL top level URLs and leave none for the rest of your site to use.  It would probably make more sense to use a structure like this:

```
router.get('/category/:category', ...)
```

With a URL of `http://localhost:3000/category/entertainment`.  Then, you can more clearly separate out the actual category requests from all the other requests in your site.  Either that or you will have to move ALL other URLs used on your site to routes that come before this and/or use sub-directories in their page such as:

```
 http://localhost:3000/scripts/sw.js
 http://localhost:3000/styles/main.css
```

Comment: Thanks fro the explanation @jfriend00. I changed the routes and it works.